# What is the effect of a perfect darkness solar manifestation?

Tags: starfinder

Solarians get  a solar manifestation that can have different colours up to perfect darkness. I'm a bit confused though:

> A glowing solar manifestation, regardless of its form,
>   sheds dim light in a 20-foot radius. You can shut off the light or
>   darkness as a standard action....

Now for a golden light I get it, but what about perfect darkness?
Does it also have some special effect there (as it can be "shut down" and I somehow don't think that it also sheds light)?

Answer (score 6):

## I don't think so.

Emphasis mine.

> You also choose whether your solar manifestation (in any form)
> either **glows** brightly with one color common to stars (including
> blue, red, white, or yellow) ***or*** is the perfect darkness of a black
> hole. A ***glowing*** solar manifestation, regardless of its form,
> sheds dim light in a 20-foot radius. You can shut off the light or
> darkness as a standard action in order to ***blend* in or assist in
> stealth**, but whenever you enter a stellar mode (see page 102),
> the glow or darkness returns immediately.

The 20-foot radius of dim light is associated with the glowing solar manifestation, it's form referencing whether it's an armor or weapon and what shape it's user chose for it.

I would imagine that a solar manifestation of perfect darkness wouldn't go unnoticed in a public area or social encounter, hence the need to turn it off in order to blend in.

Therefore I don't think a manifestation of perfect darkness sheds any light. But that might also mean you can stealth with the manifestation turned on.

Comment: Yepp don't think so too that they would shed light. Thus I thought maybe they make it darker instead but didn't find anything there and thus my confusion. If I go by how I read it it is so that complete darkness has 1 special ability less than all other colours?

Comment: Actually, it might mean you can stealth with it, unlike the glowing manifestation. Until paizo comes out with a statement on the proper ruling I would imagine. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @Blackguard I agreed with your answer but found your emphasi in the quoted section confusing. I rearranged it; I feel it better links your answer to the emphasis. If you disagree or I missed something, feel free to roll it back or reedit it to make it even better.

Comment: @Ifusaso It might have been. I'm new here and english is not my first language. Besides, you didn't change the meaning at all so I think it's fine. Please, do send criticism my way if I do anything wrong.

Comment: Of course! Welcome to the site too.

Answer (score -2):

Black does not produce light main evidence for this is at the end whenever you enter a stellar mode (see page 102), the glow **or** darkness returns immediately.

I've reworked the ability but I haven't got to test it yet:

> At 1st level, you gain a physical manifestation of your stellar power. The base form of your solar manifestation, when not actively in use, is a mote of stellar energy slightly smaller than your fist that hovers near your head. Beyond the solar mote, your manifestation can take one of two additional forms: armor or a weapon. You must pick one solar manifestation (either armor or a weapon] upon taking your first level of solarian. You also choose whether your solar manifestation (in any form) either glows brightly with one color common to stars (including blue, red, white, or yellow) or is the perfect darkness of a black hole.. You can shut off the light or darkness as a standard action in order to blend in or assist in stealth, but whenever you enter a stellar mode (see page 102), the glow or darkness returns immediately. Once made, these choices cannot be changed
>
> A glowing solar manifestation,light is produced by Solarian with their Solar mentifestion counts as a 2ed level light spell and the spell level increases by 1 at 10th level and every 5 levels after word to a max spell level of 5, A Solar mentifestion that produces dim light does so at a 20 ft radius and bright light at a 10ft radius Every 5 levels this radius increases by 5ft for both radiuses the solarian can change the area as a swift action. The light causes the illumination level in the area to go up by one step at a radius of 20ft and up 2 steps at a 10ft radius (a Solarian can NOT be blinded by their own Light)
>
> A darkness manifestation causes the illumination level in the area to drop one step at a radius of 20ft and 2 steps at a 10ft radius this increase by 1 every 10 levels. (All creatures gain concealment (20% miss chance) in dim light. All creatures gain total concealment (50% miss chance) in darkness.) Nonmagical sources of light, such as torches and lanterns, do not increase the light level in an area of darkness. Magical light sources only increase the light level in an area if they are of a higher spell level than darkness.Creatures with darkvision and the power to see in darkness have difficulty seeing through this darkness, and can see as well as a human can in dim light. Creatures in the area of darkness take a –2 penalty on saves against fear. The solarians spell level for darkness is 2ed level and increases by 1 at 15th level and then again at 20 to a max level of 4 any light spell that is cast at a higher level than the level of the darkness can negate the darkness.
>
> If in a dim-light/darkness in the area get a +40 bonus to Stealth checks, but this bonus is reduced to +20 if the creatures moves, if in a light area the creature has a -20 bonus to Stealth checks, but this bonus is reduced to -40 if the creature moves (and these bonuses are negated for potential observers with blindsense)
>
> FAQ
>
> - Yes, a Solarian is still affected by the concealment of his own darkness so he must roll d100 to confirm hits unless they have a Blind-Sense.
> - No, a solarian that picks darkness does not get the radius increase.
> - No, the stealth bonus from darkness do not stack with dealng with unseen creatures.

Comment: What issiues do you try to fix with your rework and **how does this answer the question what the effect of perfect darkness solar manifestion is**?

Comment: Note to flaggers: The post answers the question in the first sentence. (Quality of that answer is up to voters, of course.) The fact that the bulk of the answer is a tangent arguably detracts from the quality of the answer, but it doesn't make it qualify for Not An Answer flags. At worst, the only standard flag that applies to an on-topic question with a big tangent, like this one does, would be a Very Low Quality flag.